# Combining Sets in xtend

Tags: xtend

I have two sets:

```
val Set<Integer> setA = #{1, 2, 3}
val Set<Integer> setB = #{3, 4, 5} + setA
```

I would expect `setB` to contain 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

However, the `+` operator returns an instance of `Iterable`, instead of a `Set`.

Are there any xtend shortcuts that would allow me to do what I want?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there is no backed in support for a union. You may want to add an `operator_plus` for two sets and delegate to Guavas `Sets.union`.

```
def <T> Set<? extends T> operator_plus(Set<? extends T> left, Set<? extends T> right) {
  return Sets.union(left, right)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without redefining operators, you have to convert the `Iterable` to a `Set` manually.

```
val Set<Integer> setA = #{1, 2, 3}
val Set<Integer> setB = (#{3, 4, 5} + setA).toSet
```

If you have a mutable set, there is one other way: The `+=` operator, which is a shortcut for `addAll` on any collection.

```
val Set<Integer> setA = #{1, 2, 3}
val Set<Integer> setB = newHashSet(3, 4, 5)
setB += setA
```

Neither solution look particularly nice and you probably want to avoid mutability.

As suggested in the other answer, Guava's `Sets.union` method might come in handy, though I would rather import it as static extension than redefining operators. Then you can use:

```
val Set<Integer> setA = #{1, 2, 3}
val Set<Integer> setB = #{3, 4, 5}.union(setA)
```

Be careful though, `union` returns a *view* of both sets, which can change if the underlying sets are mutable.